# Pdf Layout grayed out issue in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Hello Team,
sometime I have face a issued that is anonymous error. I did not found any exception related it's.
My generated pdf show gray layer layout on middle o end of page so I am unable to see clearly Whole pdf. also I tried multiple time to find error but unable to findout because there not returning any error, No-ExceptionLog & not anything else.

**This is code :**

```
 private async Task SaveImageInDataFTPFolderAsync(StackPanel pageStackPanel, string jpgFilename)
    {
        try
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmapimg = new RenderTargetBitmap();

            var mainlayoutHeight = pageStackPanel.ActualHeight;
            var mainlayoutWidth = pageStackPanel.ActualWidth;
            int mlHeight = Convert.ToInt32(mainlayoutHeight);
            int mlWidth = Convert.ToInt32(mainlayoutWidth);

            //// / LETTER SIZE WIDTH / HEIGHT
            await renderTargetBitmapimg.RenderAsync(pageStackPanel, mlWidth, mlHeight);

            ///SAVE IMAGE IN FOLDER 
            var pixelBufferimg = await renderTargetBitmapimg.GetPixelsAsync();
            var pixels = pixelBufferimg.ToArray();
            var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
            var storageFolder = await KnownFolders.GetFolderForUserAsync(null, KnownFolderId.PicturesLibrary);
            StorageFolder projectFolder = await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.PATH_TMRTEMP, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            var file = await projectFolder.CreateFileAsync(jpgFilename, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                     BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                                    (uint)renderTargetBitmapimg.PixelWidth,
                                (uint)renderTargetBitmapimg.PixelHeight,
                                200,
                                200,
                               pixels);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
                // file1 = await projectFolder.GetFileAsync(jpgFilename);
                stream.Seek(0);
                stream.Dispose();
                renderTargetBitmapimg = null;
                //await Task.Delay(2000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { new ExceptionHelper().AddException(ex.Message, this.ToString(), "SaveImageInDataFTPFolderAsync"); }
    }
```

and **This is image of layout--**

[image]

if you have any solution please help me to know this.

Comment: Can you share the code how to the print current page ?

Comment: Yes I shared same code

Comment: I mean which line you used to call print and show print preview.

Comment: Above only use to convert uiement to image, but not print as pdf right ?

Comment: yes, and may be issue is occur from there.

Comment: Ok I will test above code to render a page, Can you provide [mcve] if it can't reproduce in our side ?

Comment: Can you try to set your dpi as 96 ?